# Customised Dropdown column using sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, dropdown

I have tried normal dropdown column in sharepoint. I want to customise that column with extensible kind of dropdown. Is that possible in anyway? The output I want should be in the form of the below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the common solution will be creating cascading drop down columns, which is not exactly what you want. Still you can have a check on [it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcTI_UQ55TM).